# Event listeners not removed in React even with useEffect hook's return callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events

I have a component which registers a key event during initialization.
This event triggers API call to fetch random Data.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const keyUpEvent = (event) => {
      if (event.code === "Enter") {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetchRandomData();
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpEvent);
    fetchRandomData();
    return () => {
      setChord({});
      document.removeEventListener("Keyup", keyUpEvent);
    };
  }, []);
```

But even with the above code, the event is not removed when I navigate between pages and trigger the event by key strokes ( <kbd>Enter</kbd> KEY ).

Based on the below image, this happens when I press the key once after multiple page navigations. ( MEMORY LEAK )

**PROBLEM :**

Why is react not removing the registered event? What is the proper way to remove event listeners..?

[image: Network Tab screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are capitalizing incorrectly. You just change `Keyup` in `removeEventListener` to `keyup`.

Comment: Im really sry . Couldn't find the difference and there were no errors in my console. By the way it worked. My bad. Thanks anyway's...